# Strapi repeatable Component Not Sending Image Obj with Populate=*

Tags: html, node.js, reactjs, strapi

This is a repeatable component of strapi:

[image: SS 1]

Api call:

[image: Api call]

```js
     {
        "id": 1,
        "attributes": {
         ../other fields
            "imgs": [
                {
                    "id": 37,
                    "title": "KeyNote Lecture",
                    "subtitle": "Felicitation in Chennai, Molaris 2022"
                },
    ../Same Objects
            ],
        }
    }
```

See API call getting the only title, subtile, id only. but the image not getting.

Please, anyone, help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is because populate=* gives only first level of relations, and image inside component is a relation of second level:

Option one (easiest) use `yarn add strapi-plugin-populate-deep`
`/api/course-director?populate=deep`

Option two use `qs`:

```
const str = qs.stringify(
  {
    populate: { imgs: { populate: ["image"] } }
  },
  { encodeValuesOnly: true }
);
```

```
populate[imgs][populate][0]=image
```

Comment: Thanks you so much. Worked for me. Strapi does not have good forum